# JSON like data format, does this have a name?

Tags: json, parsing, format

I have encountered a data set that looks like this:

```
userid:1A7
name: Joe
address: 123 Market St.
gender: M
---:
userid:2R5
name: Jane
address: 456 Bryant St.
gender: F
---:
```

Is this a standard data format? Does it have a name?

Comment: Looks like sections of YAML (separated by `---:`). For it to be valid YAML though, there would need to be a space after each `:`

Comment: Thanks, the actual data set does not have spaces after any ':'. I mis copied it above.

Comment: Not a `data-structures` question.